# Passing dynamic content to jsp:param "value" attribute

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee

Hie... I was wondering whether it is possible to send dynamic content involving "if" or "switch" functions to jsp:param "value" attribute ... one can send a single value which can be represented in the following manner

```
<jsp:param name="blah" value="<%=blah%>"/>
```

now what i mean to ask is ..

```
<jsp:param name="blah" value="<% 
                               if(blah == 1)
                               out.print("The value is 1");
                               if(blah == 2)
                               out.print("The value is 2");
                               %>"/>
```

is the above method possible.. when i do the same i get an error stating that an " = " sign is expected after the tag in value attribute ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend determining the value of `blah` prior to executing your `jsp`.  This can be done within a `servlet` using straight Java.  Once you have determined the value of `blah` place it in the request before forwarding to the `jsp`.

```
request.setAttribute("blah", "some value");
```

Then within your `.jsp` file you can reference the attribute using `jsp expression language`.

```
${blah}
```

Its best to keep as much logic out of your view (jsp) as possible.

Comment: hey kevin ... i shall try using this method .. i am new to jsp programming.. i am yet to learn how to use jsp expression lang .. i obtained the required result using spiritwalkers method .. thanks again

Answer (score 2):

would you consider to change it to

```
<% if(blah == 1){ %>
<jsp:param name="blah" value="The value is 1"/>
<%}else{%>
<jsp:param name="blah" value="The value is 2"/>
<%}%>
```

else use equivalent JSTL tags like

```
<c:choose>
   <c:when test="${blan eq 1}">
      <jsp:param name="blah" value="The value is 1"/>
   </c:when>
   <c:otherwise>
      <jsp:param name="blah" value="The value is 2"/>
   </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

@gabbi,
You do not necessarily have to have two `<jsp:forward>`, instead you can declare another variable for holding the value, like below:

```
<% 
String blahValue = ""; 
if(blah == 1){
   blahValue = "The value is 1";
}else if(blah==2){
   blahValue = "The value is 2";
}else{
   blahValue = "the value is invalid"; }
%>

<jsp:forward>
   <jsp:param name="blah" value="<%=blahValue%>"/>
</jsp:forward>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot... i changed it in the above mentioned way .. only back drop was that i had to use <jsp:forward page > element for every option .... so if i had two values for "blah" i had to use if(blah ==1){%> <jsp:forward page="test1.jsp"> <jsp:param name="blah" value="the value is 1"/></jsp:forward> <%}if (blah==2){ %><jsp:forward page="test1.jsp"> <jsp:param name="blah" value="the value is 1"/></jsp:forward>}%>